# Divisor topology, Continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, divisibility

Define $U \subseteq \Bbb{N} $ to be open if $n \in U$ implies that also every divisor of $n$ is in $U$. Collection of all such $U$ is a topology.

The task is:
We consider this topology on $\Bbb{N}$. Prove that $f:X \to X$ is continuous if and only if the following holds for all $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$: $\quad$ if $m$ divides $n$, then $f(m)$ divides $f(n)$.

I know following things:

$f:X \to Y$

1. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of $Y$, then $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$ for every $B \in \mathscr{B}$.

2.Take $x\in X$. Then $f$ is continous in $x$ if for every $U \subseteq Y$ open with $f(x) \in U$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

3. A function is continous if the preimage of every open set in $Y$ is open in $X$.

I'm not sure which definition should I use to prove my exercise. Also I don't know how a basis look like. It must be a collection such that $\bigcup  \mathscr{B} = \Bbb{N}$. Is it a set of divisors?

Comment: What is X  the first time you used it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $X=\Bbb N$ with the mentioned topology we use (2) to do the task.

$\Rightarrow$. Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous map $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$  and $m$ divides $n$. Put $U=\{x\in\Bbb N:  x$ divides $f(n)\}$. It is easy to see that the set $U$ is open in $X$. Since the map $f$ is continuous, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Since $n\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $m$ divides $n$, we have $m\in f^{-1}(U)$, so $f(m)\in U$, that is $f(m)$ divides $f(n)$.

$\Leftarrow$. Assume that for all $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$: $\quad$ if $m$ divides $n$, then $f(m)$ divides $f(n)$. Let $U\subset X$ be an arbitrary open set, $n\in f^{-1}(U)$, and $m$ be any divisor of $n$. Then $f(m)$  divides $f(n)$, so $f(m)\in U$ and $m\in f^{-1}(U)$. Thus the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.